# PHP falsely triggering 413 with nginx?

Tags: php, curl, nginx, http-status-code-413

I'm using a proxy script ([located here](https://github.com/UltraCart/two_page_trial/blob/master/rest_proxy.php)), which is for a two-step checkout (customer puts their billing information on step 1, clicks 'Next', then puts payment info on step 2).

When they click 'Next' on step 1, the proxy script accepts a `PUT` request with their entered data, then sends all of it to a 3rd party service (shopping cart).

The problem is that, on step 1 when I click submit, I get a `413 Request entity too large` error.

I spent a LOT of time making sure Nginx was configured properly (it definitely is). It's something in the PHP script which is somehow falsely triggering a `413`. I'm not a PHP expert, but that's the only thing I can think of.

Here are some reasons I believe it's not the Nginx config itself:

- The request is only about 10kb
- If I delete everything in the PHP file, it `PUT`'s the data perfectly fine. It's only this script above is somehow triggering it.
- I have all the necessary PHP variables set (there were 4 of them I believe). All are set to `128M`
- `client_max_body_size` is properly set to `32M`

Here are reasons I know it's not the 3rd party server

- It works fine on apache
- Many other people (on apache) are using it successfully

### Very Simple one-click download to try it yourself (if you feel like it)

If you want to tinker with it, download the zip, and upload to an nginx server:

- https://github.com/UltraCart/two_page_trial/archive/master.zip

You don't need to make any changes. Just upload, visit `trial-page1.html` and click the big `Order Now` button. You will see it logs `413` errors to console.

I don't even know how to go about debugging this, I would assume it's some kind of problem with the way `curl` is being used?

Comment: Extremely lazy answer - did you check the nginx.conf client_max_body_size value? [link](http://www.daveperrett.com/articles/2009/11/18/nginx-error-413-request-entity-too-large/)

Comment: Yes, as I said above it's at `32M`. :/

Comment: client_max_body_size 32M;
should be put inside server {} block, and outside location {} block.
Let's make sure. If it's ok, provide your php.ini config, which you told you set all to 128M.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing particularly nginx specific about this issue - you are adding duplicate headers...specifically, two Content-Length headers: one in your `foreach ($_SERVER as $i => $val) { ... }` loop, one explicitly in `$header[] = "Content-Type: " . $content_type;`

A few small modifications to your script are available at [this gist](https://gist.github.com/tml/6603954/revisions); note that it only scratches the surface of the things wrong with this script, even if you're willing to accept that doing a PHP proxy is a good idea to begin with...

Comment: Wow!!! That's so great... let me take a look at this. I really appreciate this so much.

Comment: It works perfect. As a sidenote, everyone keeps saying how bad a PHP Proxy is. What would be the alternative (better) solution for a situation like this?

Comment: Well, the most obvious solution that comes to mind is the one you're already using to make the request to the PHP Proxy: Javascript.